# cd /var/www: Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, debian

I'm running Debian 8.8.

Previously, I did not need `sudo` to access `/var/www/html`. However, after going through Solution 1 from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www/46371#46371) answer on askubuntu, I cannot access `/var/www` or `/var/www/html` anymore, which seems to be the exact opposite result of what was expected (I can still access `/var`).

How do I undo the mess I've caused and go back to the permissions I had before?

I've copied Solution 1 and pasted it here:

---

*Add yourself to the `www-data` group and set the setgid bit on the
`/var/www` directory such that all newly created files inherit this
group as well.*

```
sudo gpasswd -a "$USER" www-data
```

*Correct previously created files
(assuming you to be the only user of `/var/www`):*

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":www-data /var/www
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
```

*(even safer: use 640 or 2750 and manually chmod g+w file-or-dir that
needs to be writable by the webserver)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

Inputting `unicorn` into `"$USER"` should result with `"unicorn"` with quotes, instead of merely `unicorn`.